# wordpress theme can't find html to add anchor tags

Tags: html, wordpress, themes

I'm editing the [Nimble Wordpress theme] (http://www.elegantthemes.com/demo/?theme=Nimble) and I'm trying to edit the "learn more" buttons on the main page so that they will take the user to a specific section on an "about" sub-page. Right now they take the user to 3 seperate subpages, ideally I would like them to take the user to a specific section on a single "About" page.I can access the "About" page's HTML in the Wordpress editor but I can't locate the main page's html to alter the  tags. The theme only allows me to make very minor changes via the e-panel. All of the back end files are .php based and I only possess knowledge of HTML, not PHP. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. THANKS!

** Thanks for the tip! Is there a way to modify the PHP so that I can speficy 3 individual links? One link per widget?**

```
<?php 
        if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'nimble_display_services', 'on' ) ){
            $blurbs_number = apply_filters( 'et_blurbs_number', 3 );
            echo '<div id="services" class="clearfix">';
                for ( $i = 1; $i <= $blurbs_number; $i++ ){
                    $service_query = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'et_service_query_args', 'page_id=' . get_pageId( html_entity_decode( et_get_option( 'nimble_home_page_' . $i ) ) ), $i ) );
                    while ( $service_query->have_posts() ) : $service_query->the_post();
                        global $more;
                        $more = 0;
                        $page_title = ( $blurb_custom_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Blurbtitle', true ) ) && '' != $blurb_custom_title ? $blurb_custom_title : apply_filters( 'the_title', get_the_title() );
                        $page_permalink = ( $blurb_custom_permalink = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Blurblink', true ) ) && '' != $blurb_custom_permalink ? $blurb_custom_permalink : get_permalink();

                        echo '<div class="service' . ( 1 == $i ? ' first' : '' ) . ( $blurbs_number == $i ? ' last' : '' ) . '">';
                            if ( ( $page_icon = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Icon', true ) ) && '' != $page_icon )
                                printf( '<img src="%1$s" alt="%2$s" class="et_page_icon" />', esc_url( $page_icon ), esc_attr( $page_title ) );

                            echo '<h3>' . $page_title . '</h3>';

                            if ( has_excerpt() ) the_excerpt();
                            else the_content( '' );

                            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $page_permalink ) . '" class="learn-more">' . __( 'Learn More', 'Nimble' ) . '</a>';

                        echo '</div> <!-- end .service -->';
                    endwhile; 
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                }
            echo '</div> <!-- end #services -->';
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: try to provide some code (index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit learn more button link url, you will have to tweak below line of code:

```
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $page_permalink ) . '" class="learn-more">' . __( 'Learn More', 'Nimble' ) . '</a>';
```

with

```
echo '<a href="http://url-of-the-page-you-want-to-display" class="learn-more">' . __( 'Learn More', 'Nimble' ) . '</a>';
```

**P.S:** Above code will copy the same URL, specified in `href=""`, to all three widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Find index.php in your theme folder (this is the PHP file that controls your home page). Copy the code here on stackoverflow. I'll tell you what to change in this page.